# Viewing Referenced Field Images in node template

Tags: theming

I'm stuck with a probably simple problem, maybe someone can help?

I have a node (representing a **route**) which has a reference to other nodes (**points of interestes**)
Like this node.field_poi

Every field_poi has it's own images attached

from the node template I'm trying to get the images, but no way!

There are my attempts, where am I wrong?

**{{content.field_poi.0.entity.field_image.0.entity.uri.value}}**
{{kint(node.field_poi.0.entity.field_image.0.entity.uri.value)}}

If I try this, it breaks completely the page:
{{kint(node.field_poi.0.entity)}}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the slack channel #drupaltwig, I found a solution!
I leave it here, in case somebody else needs it

```
{% for curr_poi in node.field_poi %}                    

{% if curr_poi.entity.field_image.entity.uri.value is not empty %}

<img class="product-image" src="{{curr_poi.entity.field_image.entity.uri.value | image_style('app_list')}}" />

{{curr_poi.entity.title.value}}

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

---

Main hints:

- use **node** instead of **content**
- iterator is **curr_poi** do not use a index
- I used [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) drupal module in order to user the filter | image_style('app_list')

Thanks to @kekkis @markconroy